# Java execution randomly stopping

Tags: java

I really can't figure this out. I am working on an AI project to solve a 2x2 Rubiks cube. While the program is running, it will randomly pause for just a bit, maybe half a second or so, then resume. I can't figure out why this is. I don't have anything complicated that is happening and halting the execution. It is always happening when making a new Cube object, but the only thing I am doing is copying 6 arrays (for each side of the cube) which are 2x2 arrays.

Comment: It can be a lot of things. Can you paste the code that's being executed? We can't figure that out without looking at it...

Comment: Garbage Collector kicking in? (Also, solving 2x2 Rubik's cube is still AI?)

Comment: Put yourself in our shoes for a second. How do you go about solving this question? What would the answer look like?

Answer (score 0):

If

> making a new Cube object

occurs at the start of the program the lag you are experiencing is probably waiting for imports to happen try importing only the classes you need not everything from a package. ie in my most recent code i only import the classes

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

so i only i only import them instead of importing the packages

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
```